# WSO2 API-M Puppet module

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to implement a distributed architecture using API-Manager. There are several patterns to use according to WSO2 deployment guide (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Deployment+Patterns). I'm interested in pattern 4.
I would like to know if there is any puppet module already available for these new patterns or when they are planned to be released.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 hasn't released puppet modules for latest patterns. You can refer the latest (https://github.com/wso2/puppet-apim/releases/tag/v2.1.0.1).

Comment: Do you know any plan to release the new puppet modules?